# Error while calculating value in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I ran a code which calculates expenses made by the customer based on `buy` or `sell` present in the `transaction_code column`.

If `Buy` means I subtract the amount from the credit_card_limit.If `sell`  means I add the amount to the credit_card_limit.

I also checked for the presence of null values in the code and removed it.

Below is the initial table

```
+----------+------+-----------------+----------+------+----------------+
|account_id|amount|credit_card_limit|  date_map|amount|transaction_code|
+----------+------+-----------------+----------+------+----------------+
|     12345|  1000|           100000|      null|  1000|             buy|
|     12345|  1100|           100000|2020-06-02|  1100|             buy|
|     12345|   500|           100000|2020-06-02|   500|            sell|
|     12345|   200|           100000|2020-06-03|   200|             buy|
|     12345|  4000|           100000|2020-06-04|  4000|             buy|
+----------+------+-----------------+----------+------+----------------+
```

I validated the column and checked for the presence of any NULL values in it and removed it.Here you can see the first row from previous table was removed as date_map of it had null value

```
+----------+------+-----------------+----------+------+----------------+
|account_id|amount|credit_card_limit|  date_map|amount|transaction_code|
+----------+------+-----------------+----------+------+----------------+
|     12345|  1100|           100000|2020-06-02|  1100|             buy|
|     12345|   500|           100000|2020-06-02|   500|            sell|
|     12345|   200|           100000|2020-06-03|   200|             buy|
|     12345|  4000|           100000|2020-06-04|  4000|             buy|
+----------+------+-----------------+----------+------+----------------+
```

But while I tried to calculate the expenses column, the amount of the deleted row was also considered and the wrong amount was calculated. I don't know how it happens as I have already removed the row.

Below is the resultant table,here you can see the null row amount(1000) was also subtracted from 10000 and as a result instead of 99400 we are getting 98400.

```
+----------+-----------------+----------+--------+-----------+
|account_id|credit_card_limit|  date_map|expenses|credit_left|
+----------+-----------------+----------+--------+-----------+
|     12345|           100000|2020-06-02|    -600|      98400|
|     12345|           100000|2020-06-03|    -200|      97100|
|     12345|           100000|2020-06-04|   -4000|      93100|
|     12345|           100000|2020-06-05|    -900|      92200|
+----------+-----------------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

Initial Schema of my table:

```
root
 |-- account_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- credit_card_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |-- credit_card_number: long (nullable = true)
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- phone_number: long (nullable = true)
 |-- amount: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- shop: string (nullable = true)
 |-- transaction_code: string (nullable = true)
```

Below is the code I used:

```
spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("PPython").getOrCreate()

df=spark.read.json("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\sample.json",multiLine=True)

#Exploding the transaction column
df=df.selectExpr("*","explode(transactions)").select("*","col.*").drop(*['col','transactions'])

df.printSchema()
#Changing the datatype of columns to our required dataset
df=df.withColumn('account_id',col('account_id').cast(LongType()))
df=df.withColumn('amount',col('amount').cast(LongType()))
df=df.withColumn('credit_card_limit',col('credit_card_limit').cast(LongType()))
df=df.withColumn('credit_card_number',col('credit_card_number').cast(LongType()))
df=df.withColumn('phone_number',col('phone_number').cast(LongType()))
df=df.withColumn('shop',col('shop').cast(StringType()))
df=df.withColumn('first_name',col('first_name').cast(StringType()))
df=df.withColumn('last_name',col('last_name').cast(StringType()))
df=df.withColumn('transaction_code',col('transaction_code').cast(StringType()))
df=df.withColumn('date',col('date').cast(StringType()))

df=df.filter(df.date.isNotNull())
#Cleaning and Validating based on date column
df=df.withColumn('full_name',f.concat(f.col('first_name'),f.lit(' '),f.col('last_name'))).drop('first_name','last_name')
df=df.withColumn("cleaned_map", regexp_replace("date", "[^0-9T]", "")).withColumn("date_map", to_date("cleaned_map", "ddMMyyyy")).drop('cleaned_map','date')
df.select('account_id','amount','credit_card_limit','date_map','amount','transaction_code').show(5)

finaldf=df.filter(df.date_map.isNotNull())

#Cleaning the data which has null values
finaldf=finaldf.filter(df.account_id.isNotNull())
finaldf=finaldf.filter(df.credit_card_number.isNotNull())
finaldf=finaldf.filter(df.transaction_code.isNotNull())

finaldf=finaldf.filter(df.amount.isNotNull())


finaldf =finaldf.fillna(0, subset=['amount'])


#Validate the columns if they have any additional characters,punctuations
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('phone_number',regexp_replace("phone_number","[^0-9]",""))
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('account_id',regexp_replace("account_id","[^0-9]",""))
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('credit_card_limit',regexp_replace("credit_card_limit","[^0-9]",""))
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('credit_card_number',regexp_replace("credit_card_number","[^0-9]",""))
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('amount',regexp_replace("amount","[^0-9 ]",""))
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('full_name',regexp_replace("full_name","[^a-zA-Z ]",""))
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('transaction_code',regexp_replace("transaction_code","[^a-zA-Z]",""))
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('shop',regexp_replace("shop","[^a-zA-Z ]",""))

finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('account_id',col('account_id').cast(LongType()))
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('amount',col('amount').cast(LongType()))
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('credit_card_limit',col('credit_card_limit').cast(LongType()))
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('credit_card_number',col('credit_card_number').cast(LongType()))
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn('phone_number',col('phone_number').cast(LongType()))

#Making the first letter of the Names as Capital letters and also trimming the extra spaces present in the names
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn("full_name",initcap(col("full_name"))).withColumn("full_name",regexp_replace(col("full_name"),'\s+',' '))

#Masking the credit card number
finaldf=finaldf.withColumn("credit_card_number", expr("concat(translate(left(credit_card_number, 8), '0123456789', '**********'), " +
      "right(credit_card_number, 4))"))

#Grouping the columns based on conditions
w = Window.partitionBy(f.lit(0)).orderBy('date_map')
finaldf.select('account_id','amount','credit_card_limit','date_map','amount','transaction_code').show(4)
finaldf=finaldf.groupBy('account_id','full_name','credit_card_limit','credit_card_number','date_map','phone_number').agg(f.sum(f.when(f.col('transaction_code')=='buy',-f.col('amount')).\
              otherwise(f.col('amount'))).alias('expenses')).\
    select('*',(f.col('credit_card_limit')+f.sum(f.col('expenses')).over(w)).alias('credit_left'))

#Arranging the table based on account_id,date
finaldf=finaldf.orderBy('account_id','date_map')
finaldf.drop('phone_number','full_name','credit_card_number').show(5)
```

Required output:

```
+----------+-----------------+----------+--------+-----------+
|account_id|credit_card_limit|  date_map|expenses|credit_left|
+----------+-----------------+----------+--------+-----------+
|     12345|           100000|2020-06-02|    -600|      99400|
|     12345|           100000|2020-06-03|    -200|      99200|
|     12345|           100000|2020-06-04|   -4000|      95200|
+----------+-----------------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

This code works correctly if I don't remove any row but doesn't work when I remove a row.Please help me to find the bug in this code thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code you posted. I tried the same code and it gave the required output you posted.

Comment: Then I think there may be a bug with my other part of code.I have updated now with my complete code.Please check again and tell Sir. Thanks for your help !!